# Generate Openapi/swagger för Logic App (Standard)

Tags: openapi, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

For Consumption type Logic apps we can call the [listSwagger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/list-swagger) endpoint to generate swagger documentation.

How can I generate swagger documentation for a Logic app (standard)?

Answer (score 1):

**As for as i know it currently stands or seems to be that swagger or Open Api cannot be integrated with Standard Logic apps.**

As per the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare#create-build-and-deploy-options), there are currently few options for ***standard logic apps***

[image]

***For Consumption logic apps:***
[image]

For full information refer the above Microsoft Documentation.

Comment: We're using VS Code to create the standard logic apps. I think you are correct that exposing swagger for http triggered standard logic apps is not supported.

Comment: Please avoid posting images of text.  Instead, insert the text itself (Stack Overflow supports tables) with a proper citation to its source.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a support for built-in APIM connector for Logic Apps Standard in 2023, please see the blog

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/announcement-apim-connector-for-logic-apps-standard/ba-p/3814125